Is copy elision in the form of named return value optimization permitted in C?
Is the following C program guaranteed to exit with 0 or is the compiler allowed to identify the objects s and t with one another as is permitted in C++ as the so-called named return value optimization (NRVO) form of copy elision?
typedef struct {
    int i, j;
    double a, b;
} S;

int result;

S test(S *q) {
    S s = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    result = &s == q;
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
  S t = test(&t);
  return result;
}

Clang exits with 1 against my expectations, see https://godbolt.org/z/ME8sPGn3n.
(In C++, both 0 and 1 are valid outcomes due to explicit permission to perform NRVO.)

Your program invokes undefined behavior so you should not expect anything.

@0___________ Could you point out to me what part is UB? Assuming I didn't stupidly overlook something obvious, I am at least pretty sure that this doesn't have UB in C++ and I don't see where it would differ in C.

In C++ too. https://godbolt.org/z/nEos6ojch

It also returns 1 in C++.

@0___________ Yes, in C++ both exit codes 0 and 1 are permitted and it is unspecified which one will be chosen. It isn't UB though. The question is whether this is different in C.

@BradLanam See comment above.

Given s is local to test(), and q = &s;, accessing the value of q after test() returns is UB.

@AndrewHenle OK, it is implementation-defined in C++. But I removed that variation again. It probably just distracted from my point.

@user17732522 I am not aware of any C equivalent of NRVO, so I'd say based on that the C return value should be 0 as s is local to test() and t is local to main().  They are two distinct objects that both have their addresses taken, so they'd have to have different addresses.  You seem to have found a compiler bug.

@user17732522 I suspect that if you didn't take the address(es) of the objects, under the "as-if" rule [N]RVO would be perfectly acceptable in C as there would be none of the side effects that are possible in C++ when objects are copied.  Of course, without taking the address(s), you'd never be able to observe such behavior from within your code.

@AndrewHenle Of course. Whether the compiler optimizes away the copy is in itself usually not observable and then it can be done in both C and C++ under the general "as-if" rules applying to all optimizations. The NRVO rule in C++ is there because it explicitly permits such an optimization to be done even if it has observable side effects. It is much easier to generate observable side effects in C++, but as this example shows, it is also possible in C when taking addresses.

@user17732522 I added this: NRVO used in C mode

@TedLyngmo You used my variation that I have deleted in the mean time, which, as pointed out to me in a previous comment, has UB in C. You should have posted the original variation that is still in the question instead.

@TedLyngmo In C using a pointer whose value points to an object outside its lifetime is UB, as happens for ptr when you compare in main. (In C++ such a use of a pointer value has implementation-defined behavior, with the usual choice being that the pointer value still behaves as if it represented the original address of the object for the purpose of ==.)

@user17732522 I updated the ticket with your current code.

Are there two or three S objects? Two. Object has to be "defined". Return value is not an object. It's a value.

@KamilCuk I noticed that it doesn't matter anyway, because lifetime of s in C beings already when its block is entered, so it will have to have a unique address during all of the relevant processing anyway. But I wonder whether there really are no temporary objects. Draft N3220 at least describes objects with temporary lifetime for non-lvalue expressions of structure/union type with array members in §6.2.4. I suppose that's necessary because one can form a pointer into the array member.

@KamilCuk Also, interestingly §6.2.4 also says about objects with temporary lifetime: "Such an object may not have a unique address". This effectively means that the equivalent of copy elision in the form of return value optimization (RVO instead of NRVO) is permitted in C. The address of the temporary object would be the only observable difference when applying this optimization in C.

As a general rule, if there's an optimization that's clearly allowed in C++, and either not clearly allowed or clearly not allowed in C, and you find that clang does this optimization for C, you should assume clang is buggy, especially if a different compiler doesn't do the same thing.

@user17732522, you're reading more into that than is actually there.  The only intent of temporary lifetime is to harmonize the semantics of accessing elements of an array contained as a sub-object of a non-lvalue expression.  Even if your type S were one that afforded objects with temporary lifetime -- it is not -- that provision would not permit (observable) NVRO involving it.  A temporary object could conceivably be identified with one of the named objects involved in returning a structure by value, but that doesn't identify the source and destination with each other.

@JohnBollinger Yes, that's why I specified that this is equivalent to RVO, not NRVO, in C++ (prior to C++17 which eliminated temporary objects as function result objects). I was not talking about the example in the question. RVO would be the identification of the temporary result object of a function call with the variable which is initialized from it.

Ok, @user17732522, but you don't need temporary lifetime for that. There is no way in C to discriminate between whether (anonymous) RVO is performed or not, so it is allowed under the as-if rule, and always has been.  My understanding is that many compilers do it.

@JohnBollinger Hm, for types without array members it is clearly unobservable, but I thought maybe the implicit array-to-pointer conversion would allow observing the temporary object's address. But the only way I manage to do that will cause the temporary object to no longer initialize a variable.

It is guaranteed to exit with 0. t and s are different objects, pointers to them can't compare equal.

About the code that you removed:

What about the following variation in which relevant lifetime considerations may be different?

From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2 :

The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

It may return 1 or 0 or perform a trap.

It's now also confirmed to be a bug in clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/100902#issuecomment-2256438613

Worth noting that the optimization would be allowed if the program didn't try to observe it !

Copy / move elision is a C++ concept, defined in section 15.8.3 of C++17.  It allows for optimizing away constructor and destructor calls in some cases in which case the source and destination objects are one in the same:

When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
different ways of referring to the same object.

C has no such provision, although as of C17 it allows an object with temporary lifetime, e.g. an array contained in a struct in a non-lvalue expression, to not have a unique address.  This isn't applicable to this case however.
The fact that this optimization was performed on a C program changes the observable behavior of the program in violation of the C standard.  Specifically, t and s are distinct objects whose lifetime overlaps and as such they must have different addresses.
So this is a bug in clang that copy elision is being applied to a C program.

Re “C has no such provision”: Except, as user17732522 noted, a returned object with temporary lifetime may have the same address as another object.

@EricPostpischil Interesting, it seems the part about not having a unique address was added in C17.

There are a variety of reasons for programs to perform equality comparisons between pointers, and in many cases such comparisons could be most usefully treated as yielding either 0 or 1 in unspecified side-effect-free fashion.  In this example, the last time s is accessed will precede the first time t is accessed, and thus using the same storage for both would allow code to be more efficient.  Even though the objects technically have overlapping lifetime, it would be rare for code that would compare their addresses to care about the result of the comparison, especially since most of the things code would typically do based on the result of the comparison would make it necessary to assign the objects distinct addresses.
While behaving in this fashion in a mode that is supposed to be conforming might be considered a 'bug', a compilation mode that allows objects to share addresses in some cases not allowed by the Standard may for some purposes be more useful than one which precisely adheres to the Standard.  For example, although the Standard would specify that all static const structures have unique addresses, it would often be more useful for compilers to consolidate their addresses.  Unfortunately, compiler documentation often fails to adequately document the corner cases where behavior might deviate from Dennis Ritchie's language or the Standard.
